# joomla site not opening at all

Tags: joomla

Suddenly, out of nowhere, each time I am trying to open the site I'm getting this nonesense:

```
Joomla! Logo
yoursdproperty.com
```

This site is currently undergoing redesign to add new features. Please check back again soon!

how do I reopen it?

Comment: Is this a real question?

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIllllIlIlIlIlllllllII: On an unrelated note, that is easily the most annoying username I've ever seen on StackOverflow. Are you one of those people who gets license plates with mixed numbers of "0" and "O"s in the hopes that the police will issue parking tickets against the wrong license plate? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla has an offline mode that can be switched on and off in the administration panel.

[**Here's how to turn it back to online mode**](http://www.mightyjoomla.com/Joomla-Tips-Tricks/how-to-take-joomla-website-to-offline-mode.html)

[**Here's how to customize the offline message**](http://www.dart-creations.com/joomla/joomla-tips-and-tricks/19-changing-the-offline-message.html)